# How to track multiple subdomains in the same web site with google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two subdomains for which I created two different google analytics IDs (`UA-00000000-1` and `UA-00000000-2`). How can I track them in the same web site?

Comment: Basically you need to insert different ones on different pages of the same site.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable subdomain tracking under admin > tracking and then create two separate profiles for each subdomain. The benefit if this is that you could have a roll up profile to compare the sites against each other.

If you're using Google Analytics (ga.js), your base code should look something like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-9']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'yourwebsitetopleveldomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  </script>
```

Comment: In this case where should i put the script ? (if it's just one!)

Comment: Put the same script on every page of both the subdomains. Just make sure that your tracking script include the _setDomainName method. For example, your code should look something like this (see answer above code example).

Comment: What if the pages are the same, just the domains are different. What should I do?